# Can't import module in node/express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting an error when importing files into my node js server file.
I usually do it in this way and all the paths are correct so I'm not sure what the error is.

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

import data from '../data.js'
import Page from "../models/pageModel.js";

const app = express()
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/note-guard', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
  });
app.use('/api/pages/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const createdPages = await Page.insertMany(data.pages);
  console.log(createdPages);
  res.send("test");
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5002;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/data.js' imported from /Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/backend/server.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:265:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `ls -l /Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/data.js`? What's the output?

Comment: ```charlielamb@Charlies-MacBook-Air note-guard % ls -l backend/data.js
-rw-r--r--  1 charlielamb  staff  269  3 Jul 15:46 backend/data.js```

Comment: Where does `backend` come from? That's the wrong path. The file should be in `/Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/data.js` or you have to use different import paths.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use `import` expression in nodejs you should add following line to your package.json file: `"type": "module"`. it's after `"main": "index.js"` and before: `"scripts"` section.
On the other hand you should use `const express = require('express')` type of expressions

Also you should have the right structure of your project for package.json to be able recognize all your files as "module"

```
right:

root - client
          - package.json for client
     - server
          - package.json for server

wrong:

root - client
          - package.json
     - server
     - package.json
```

In order to help you I made a video about this
https://youtu.be/NAq3P_QCcOg

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue and have already done this, after I did that I now have this error

Comment: Which folder your package.json is located?

Comment: I have two, one package.json is in the root folder and the other in frontend

Comment: the server.js file is in the backend folder aswell.

Comment: got it. Could you please provide data.js code?
I guess its because you should have two separated folders with package.json, that don't in each others

Comment: ```import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const data = {
  pages: {
    pageName: "charlie",
    titleList: ["title1", "title2"],
    noteList: ["hi", "hello"],
    editorPassword: bcrypt.hashSync("edit"),
    viewerPassword: bcrypt.hashSync("view"),
  },
};

export default data;```

Comment: Yeah, nodejs doesn't know that your data.js is also a type of "module"

Comment: check answer for the illustration of the right structure. You need two separated folders with their own package.json files

Comment: Tell me if it's helped you

Comment: I've followed the structure in the answer and I'm still getting this error, when i changed the package.json file in the root folder it altered the result in the backend folder so I don't think that this was the issue?

Comment: You don't need root package.json, you just need one in frontend folder and one in backend folder. The issue happens because of interference of multiple package.json files. And none of the package.json file above each folder

Comment: Thanks, I now get this error? ```npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/charlielamb/Desktop/learnCode/note-guard/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/charlielamb/.npm/_logs/2021-07-03T16_38_41_686Z-debug.log```

Comment: Now you need to write npm start in your backend folder

Comment: I now get the same error as I had initially.

Comment: Well, maybe some misunderstanding happening now. Can you please provide detailed description of your structure as a screenshot or by scheme, to help me continue with solving your issue?

Comment: added it as an answer.

Comment: Now I can see. In your backend folder you don't have node_modules. It means that you not installed express and mongoose from npm. You need to go to backend folder and in terminal run **npm install express mongoose**

Comment: Also tell me, how do you added package.json in backend folder, did you run **npm init** in backend folder?

Comment: I can record a video special for you how to setup similar project, will you watch it?

Comment: Thanks, ran the command in the backend folder and I still get the same error and there wasnt a node_modules folder created in the backend. I'm not sure whats gone wrong

Comment: just refreshed and there is node modules now but still get the error.

Comment: Something went wrong in setting up project

Comment: I have a chance to help you and promote my youtube channel, let's help each other?

Comment: I'm posted a video, checkout my answer for the link

Comment: Thanks for all the help, appreciate it :)

Comment: "On the other hand you should use const express = require('express') type of expressions" - Why?

Answer (score 0):

`server.js`, `data.js` and `models` are in the same path. Fix the import paths:

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

import data from './data.js'
import Page from "./models/pageModel.js";

const app = express()
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/note-guard', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
  });
app.use('/api/pages/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const createdPages = await Page.insertMany(data.pages);
  console.log(createdPages);
  res.send("test");
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5002;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```